# convert xml data issue in array in php

Tags: php, xml, oop, parsing, zend-framework

```
$data = 
    '<parent>
       <child>
         <EC>1</EC>
         <Descript>Savings Accepted</Descript>
         <Logic>RF > LF = PAID</Logic>
         <Rules>RF is greater than PAID and LF is equal to PAID</Rules>
       </child>
       <child>
         <EC>2</EC>
         <Descript>Savings Declined</Descript>
         <Logic>RF >= LF < PAID</Logic>
         <Rules>RF greater/equal PAID, LF equal PAID</Rules>
       </child>
     </parent>';

file_put_contents('rules.xml', $data);

$xml = simplexml_load_file("rules.xml")  or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

i am not able to convert.

Comment: $data = '<parent><child><EC>1</EC><Descript>Savings Accepted</Descript><Logic>RF > LF = PAID</Logic><Rules>RF is greater than PAID and LF is equal to PAID</Rules></child><child><EC>2</EC><Descript>Savings Declined</Descript><Logic>RF >= LF < PAID</Logic><Rules>RF greater/equal PAID, LF equal PAID</Rules></child></parent>';
file_put_contents('rules.xml', $data);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("rules.xml") 
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: You can edit the question, or you can delete and create a new one. Please specify what is the current output and what would be the expected one.

Comment: Does `file_put_contents('rules.xml', $data);` create correct the file? Can you open it in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should use entities &lt; instead of < and &gt; instead of >

```
$data = <<<'XML'
<parent><child>
    <EC>1</EC>
    <Descript>Savings Accepted</Descript>
    <Logic>RF &gt; LF = PAID</Logic>
    <Rules>RF is greater than PAID and LF is equal to PAID</Rules>
</child>
<child>
    <EC>2</EC>
    <Descript>Savings Declined</Descript>
    <Logic>RF &gt;= LF &lt; PAID</Logic>
    <Rules>RF greater/equal PAID, LF equal PAID</Rules>
</child></parent>
XML;
file_put_contents('rules.xml', $data);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("rules.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

print_r($xml);
```

Ouput

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [child] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [EC] => 1
                    [Descript] => Savings Accepted
                    [Logic] => RF > LF = PAID
                    [Rules] => RF is greater than PAID and LF is equal to PAID
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [EC] => 2
                    [Descript] => Savings Declined
                    [Logic] => RF >= LF  RF greater/equal PAID, LF equal PAID
                )

        )

)
```

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_character_entities.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: HI richard i want to change the data not manualy so how can i do it because xml data coming from third party service

Comment: Hello Sandeep, the xml is not valid. Who's is sending you that? Can you call them and tell them that the xml is not valid? That would be probably the best way how to deal with it.